# Spring Boot: modeling same entity across multiple databases with dblink

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-data-jpa, entity

I have one database `MAIN_DB` that has dblinks to other databases: `EMP_DB1`, `EMP_DB2`, `EMP_DB3`, `EMP_DBx`. Let's assume two other databases for simplicity.

`EMP_DB1` and `EMP_DB2` both have the table `EMPLOYEE` with the same table structure:

```
create table employee(
id number primary key,
first_name varchar2(40),
last_name varchar2(40));
```

`MAIN_DB` is able to query `EMP_DB1` and `EMP_DB2` through their `dblink`:

```
select * from employee@emp_db1;
1  John  Smith

select * from employee@emp_db2;
2  Jane  Doe
```

I would like for my `RestController` to listen on `/employee/{id}` and query the corresponding `EMP_DBx` depending on the `id`.

**Current working (not ideal) example:**

**com.apitest.repository.PersonRepository**

```
package com.apitest.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

@NoRepositoryBean
interface PersonRepository<T> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
}
```

**com.apitest.repository.EmployeeRepository**

```
package com.apitest.repository;

import com.apitest.model.Employee;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends PersonRepository<Employee> {
    Employee findById(Long id);
}
```

**com.apitest.repository.Employee2Repository**

```
package com.apitest.repository;

import com.apitest.model.Employee2;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface Employee2Repository extends PersonRepository<Employee2> {
    Employee2 findById(Long id);
}
```

**com.apitest.model.Person**

```
package com.apitest.model;

...

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Person {
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "id: " + id + ", " +
                "first_name: " + firstName + ", " +
                "last_name: " + lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Person employee = (Person) o;
        return id == employee.id &&
                Objects.equals(firstName, employee.firstName) &&
                Objects.equals(lastName, employee.lastName);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, firstName, lastName);
    }
}
```

**com.apitest.model.Employee**

```
package com.apitest.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity(name = "EMPLOYEE@EMP_DB1")
public class Employee extends Person {

}
```

**com.apitest.model.Employee2**

```
package com.apitest.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity(name = "EMPLOYEE@EMP_DB2")
public class Employee2 extends Person {

}
```

**com.apitest.controller.EmployeeController**

```
package com.apitest.controller;

...

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {
    private final EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    private final Employee2Repository employee2Repository;

    @Autowired
    public EmployeeController(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository, Employee2Repository employee2Repository) {
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
        this.employee2Repository = employee2Repository;
    }

    // logic will be different, this is just an example
    @RequestMapping(path = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getByUserid(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        if (id % 2 == 1) {
            Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(ResponseEntity.ok(employee), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        else {
            Employee2 employee2 = employee2Repository.findById(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(ResponseEntity.ok(employee2), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to parameterize the `Entity` name?

```
@Entity(name = "EMPLOYEE@{db_link_name}")
public class Employee extends Person
```

If not, how can I query a dblink with `@Query`?

**EmployeeRepository**:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
    @Query("select e from employee@emp_dbx e e.id = ?1")
    Employee findById(Long id);
}
```

Spring doesn't like the `@dblink_name` in the query string. I'm able to create synonyms to get around this, but I'm unable to parameterize the synonym name:

```
create or replace synonym employee_emp_db1 for employee@emp_db1;
create or replace synonym employee_emp_db2 for employee@emp_db2;

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
    @Query("select e from ?1 e e.id = ?2")
    Employee findById(String dblinkName, Long id);
}

QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ? near line 1, column 15 [select e from ?1 e e.id = ?2]
```

**Desired behavior:**

```
GET /employee/1
{
    "headers": {},
    "body": {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Smith"
    },
    "statusCode": "OK",
    "statusCodeValue": 200
}

GET /employee/2
{
    "headers": {},
    "body": {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    "statusCode": "OK",
    "statusCodeValue": 200
}
```

My question boils down to what is the best design done Spring-fully and how can I achieve this?

Comment: I think this is on the borderline of being too broad / opinionated ... consider looking into [mcve] and ways to *minimize* your code input.

Comment: @GhostCat I added the different things I tried for completeness, but I can see how that makes it too broad. I'll break it up into separate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement Multi-Tenant architecture. It will be the correct design pattern to use for your use-case. 
Check out this link to make your spring/spring-boot app multi-tenant.
https://fizzylogic.nl/2016/01/24/make-your-spring-boot-application-multi-tenant-aware-in-2-steps/

Comment: This is a great solution! Thank you for the link.